# Can a probe with readout actuator be used on a scope without readout feature?

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

Some oscilloscopes can detect the attenuation set on the probes in use ("readout"), if the probes have the corresponding protruding activator pin. The probes are mostly offered with or without this feature. The former beeing more expensive.

Can such a probe with readout actuator be used on a scope, which doesn't have this readout feature?

I found a decent probe kit which is only availabe with readout. Also it could be useful should I buy a scope with readout later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  You will, of course, have to set your scope manually to match the attenuation of the probe.

Comment: Great, i was afraid that it might be mechanically incompatible.